# titan core 2.0 bug : com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer too small: capacity: 2, required: 8

Tags: titan

I have a titan graph setup using following versions of software.

Cassandra version : 2.0.6

Titan version : 0.4.2

5 cassandra server with replication factor 3.

Recently, all of sudden,  we have started getting following error intermittently.

com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer too small: capacity: 2, required: 8

I searched net and found that there is a bug filed relating to same error. Bug is pertaining to kryo API. https://code.google.com/p/kryo/issues/detail?id=124

Fix of above bug is not incorporated in titan-0.4.2 version.

On cassandra server we have not run repair database for many days (6 months). Can it be the issue with inconsistent data on cassandra server?

Can you please suggest the reason for this bug and how to approach solving it?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from this issue (which discusses Faunus, but is likely very related), i'm not so sure that there is a solution:

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/809

According to the issue, it looks like the 0.4.x solution was to change the hardcoded limit and recompile:

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/0.4.4/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/database/serialize/kryo/KryoSerializer.java#L37

Comment: I don't think our data size will ever be greater than 10 mb as is mentioned in KryoSerializer. So, i doubt it will fix our problem. Moreover , how it (bug) started to appear all of a sudden is still a mystery. Has it to do with data corruption in cassandra server ?

Comment: I'm not aware of this issue outside of the link I provided.  I can't say for sure if it has anything to do with not running repairs or other corruption, however not running appropriate cassandra maintenance can bring unwanted trouble for sure.